# mesg: ttyname failed: no such device

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

Im working on LFS, and I finished the process of compiling, and came to the part of entering the cheroot Environment, with the code provide.

But I’m getting this error:`mesg: ttyname failed: no such device`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `mesg n` command in you /root/.profile or so. Just comment it out or ensure it is run only if running on a tty with `test -t 0 && mesg n`.